# Spark: how to process certain column content individually in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The data structure is like this:

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | aaa | true,false,false |
| 002 | bbb | true,true,true |
| 003 | ccc | false,true,true |

I want to map the results in data to their names by their corresponding orders in the mapping table. In detail, the first step is to get the order number of False in data and then get the name by order number in the mapping table.

For example, the first record has two False and their index numbers are 2 and 3, so the mapping result is code2 and code3. Also, there are all true in the second record so the mapping result is an empty string.

the mapping table: `("code1","code2","code3")`

the expected result:

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | aaa | code2,code3 |
| 002 | bbb |  |
| 003 | ccc | code1 |

Is it possible to achieve this in the dataframe?

Comment: can you elaborate how true,false,false maps to code2,code3 and true,true,true maps to nothing?

Comment: @linusRian Sorry for forgetting to mention the mapping logic. The details are already updated.

Comment: cnidaye, thank you ,sorry for the delay, I can see that this has already been answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work but be aware that it features a `posexplode` (`explode` an `array` with positional value) which can be a costly operation specially if you have a huge dataset.

```scala
val df = Seq(
("001", "aaa", "true,false,false"),
("002", "bbb", "true,true,true"),
("003", "ccc", "false,true,true")
).toDF("id", "name", "data")

val codes = Seq(
(0, "code1"),
(1, "code2"),
(2, "code3")
).toDF("code_id", "codes")


val df1 = df.select($"*", posexplode(split($"data", ",")))
  .join(codes, $"pos" === $"code_id")
  .withColumn( "codes", when($"col" === "false", $"codes").otherwise(null) )

//+---+----+----------------+---+-----+-------+-----+
//| id|name|            data|pos|  col|code_id|codes|
//+---+----+----------------+---+-----+-------+-----+
//|001| aaa|true,false,false|  0| true|      0| null|
//|001| aaa|true,false,false|  1|false|      1|code2|
//|001| aaa|true,false,false|  2|false|      2|code3|
//|002| bbb|  true,true,true|  0| true|      0| null|
//|002| bbb|  true,true,true|  1| true|      1| null|
//|002| bbb|  true,true,true|  2| true|      2| null|
//|003| ccc| false,true,true|  0|false|      0|code1|
//|003| ccc| false,true,true|  1| true|      1| null|
//|003| ccc| false,true,true|  2| true|      2| null|
//+---+----+----------------+---+-----+-------+-----+

val finalDf = df1.groupBy($"id", $"name").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"codes")).as("data"))

//+---+----+-----------+
//| id|name|       data|
//+---+----+-----------+
//|002| bbb|           |
//|001| aaa|code2,code3|
//|003| ccc|      code1|
//+---+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I also agree this will be a costly operation, so I am considering whether it is more efficient if I use `df.map()`  function and put my processing logic inside  `map()` function?  It seems like reducing the extra IO pressure as the mapping table is stored in every machine and just process them locally?

Comment: @cnidaye If you can't use the Spark 3 answer below, you could also try and compare the performance with a Spark UDF. Your operation should be easy to implement in a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **spark 3+** you can use `filter` and `transform` functions as

```
val df = Seq(
  ("001", "aaa", "true,false,false"),
  ("002", "bbb", "true,true,true"),
  ("003", "ccc", "false,true,true"),
).toDF("id", "name", "data")

val cols = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")

val dfNew = df.withColumn("data", split($"data", ","))
  .withColumn("mapping", arrays_zip($"data", typedLit(cols)))
  .withColumn("new1", filter($"mapping", (c: Column) => c.getField("data") === "false"))
  .withColumn("data", transform($"new1", (c: Column) => c.getField("1")))
  .drop("new1", "mapping")

dfNew.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+----+------------+
|id |name|data        |
+---+----+------------+
|001|aaa |[col2, col3]|
|002|bbb |[]          |
|003|ccc |[col1]      |
+---+----+------------+
```